# Spring Boot HandlerInterceptor not triggered when a request is authenticated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

As described in the title, the interceptor is only triggered if the request does not contain the required auth token. With the token, the interceptor does not get triggerd...

How can this be prevented so that the interceptor gets triggerd on all requests?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the order property to the lowest.
Maybe @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) might do the job.
If not, check this out: https://kreepcode.com/spring-boot-define-execution-order-multiple-interceptors/